# Java Printing at anything above 72 DPI doesn't fill page

Tags: java, opengl, printing, dpi

I am writing a jOGL application that allows for the user to print a screenshot of the current render. In order to print out the render, I set the OpenGL context's size to the printable area of the paper and then save the front buffer to an image that is drawn to the Printable canvas.

The application must also print out these screenshots at the highest quality possible, so I've been trying to up the DPI from the 72 default to 300. However, instead of the resolution of the image increasing, it stays the same and only now fills up about 1/4th of the page. Any idea why this is happening?

Here's the printing code:

```
    // Set up for printing
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

    PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    PrinterResolution pr =
      new PrinterResolution(300, 300, PrinterResolution.DPI);

    aset.add(pr);

    aset.add(PrintQuality.HIGH);

    boolean ok = job.printDialog(aset);
    if (ok) {
        try {
            Book book = new Book();

            PageFormat pf = job.getPageFormat(aset);
            Paper paper = pf.getPaper();

            // Halve margins
            paper.setImageableArea(pf.getImageableX()/2, pf.getImageableY()/2, pf.getImageableWidth() + pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableHeight() + pf.getImageableY());
            pf.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);

            pf.setPaper(paper);

            book.append(glcanvas, pf, 2);

            job.setPageable(book);
            job.print(aset);
        }
    }
```

Then, in my printable object, I resize the OpenGL context:

```
    glcanvas.reshape(0, 0, (int)pf.getImageableWidth(), (int) pf.getImageableHeight() - StaticViewerUtility.HEADER_HEIGHT);
```

However, the imagable size of the PageFormat never changes. It stays at 72, 72, 468, 648 (that's 72 DPI with 1" margins on 8.5"x11" paper). Even with the DPI set to 300 the imagable area doesn't change. Forcing it any higher just makes the printer see the page as an arbitrary size (ex: 22.87232"x11.8892") and the image is still only printed out to a corner of the page. I've also tried manually changing the size of the OpenGL context, but the printout is still cut off at the exact dimensions it was originally.

Example screenshot of problem:
http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/2708/capturedodg.jpg

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Where's your `glViewport()` call?  Is it taken care of by this "jOGL" thing?

Comment: Yes, when I call glcanvas.reshape() jOGL reinitializes the OpenGL context, which has the viewport call (glViewport(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);). The problem is that the pageable area of the print never changes, so it's a problem even before the OpenGL context is resized.

Answer (score 2):

> so I've been trying to up the DPI from the 72 default to 300

OpenGL creates a raster image, which means you have a fixed amount of pixels. The resolution (DPI) tells the printer how many pixels there are to an inch. If you increase the DPI the fixed amount of pixels will cover only a shorter length. To compensate this you need to render with OpenGL at a accordingly higher resolution.

Taking a picture from a window has it's problems. I strongly recommend using a off-screen buffer, like a PBuffer or a Frame Buffer Object.

---

OpenGL being a rasterizer aimed at realtime graphics is not so suitaable for feeding printers anyway (printers love vector graphics as data input, but the output of OpenGL is a raster image).

The commonly used method for high quality printing with OpenGL is the following:

- Determine target size and resolution of image. E.g. 10inch × 20inch at 300DPI. Thus the required resolution is 3000×6000 pixels.
- There's a maximum size for framebuffers; OpenGL requires at least 4096×4096 being supported. With features like EyeFinity you've got tens of thousands of pixels. But let's say your implementation can deal with 4096×4096 max only. So you can't fit the 3000×6000 in it. The solution is tiled rendering. You split up your picture into 2× 3000×3000

  ```
  for t in tiles:
      glViewport(0, 0, t.width, t.height)
      glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
      glScalef(total_width / t.width, total_height / t.height, 1)
      glTranslatef(-1 + 2*total_width / t.off_x, -1 + 2*total_height / t.off_y, 0)
      your_projection()
      render_scene()
  ```

  Then merge the tiles into a large picture.

Another nice method is translating OpenGL into vector output: http://geuz.org/gl2ps/ (unfortunately this library seems to support immediate mode only). If you still want to use the GPU and have modern features available you can use transform feedback as well.

Comment: Many of our clients will be running this application on laptops with integrated graphics (meaning many of them will be running OpenGL 2.0 or lower), so a PBuffer or FBO aren't a viable option. For debugging purposes I have the code also saving the front buffer to a JPG before printing. The JPG is the correct size, and there are no problems there, even when resizing the viewport by a factor of 300/72 (scaled up from 72 to 300 DPI). The problem is that my pageable size does not change, so even when OpenGL is rendering out the correct size it's being cropped back down by the printing operation.

Comment: Contents of front buffer, saved: http://img864.imageshack.us/img864/4925/saved.png What's getting sent to the printer: http://img831.imageshack.us/img831/4/capturesmj.jpg

Comment: @Nicholas'Snobaste'Fetcko: PBuffers have been around since the late 1990-ies (I remember writing my first PBuffer based program in 1999), so that's absolutely no showstopper. Also if you first render to JPG and then print, you'll not gain resolution, but just scale up. It should be noted, that you can not (well should not) OpenGL on a printer DC (see my edit in the answer).

Comment: I understand that saving the front buffer is obviously not the best way to go about printing, but that is not the problem. Even when printing out vector graphics (drawn using the Java Graphics library) I'm locked into the top left corner of the page.

Comment: @Nicholas'Snobaste'Fetcko: The DPI setting doesn't magically scale your images. Say you want a picture printed 10" wide with a 300DPI setting, then the image dimensions must be in the reade 0...3000. So leaving the image dimensions untouched, varying the resolution (DPI) will change the physical size of the outcome.